# why does java.util.list adds previous data which were cleared when adding new data

Tags: java, mysql

I created a spider program .

There is a problem that some data are repeated  when inserting data into MySQL database.

For example,when the program have inserted the data of A,it firstly inserts some values of A's field into database before inserting the data of B,then inserting B.

in database>>>>>

[please click to check the exmple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmk5r.jpg)

B does not have the red data but  still inserted .
I cleared list before inserting B ,however it does not work.

When I debuging:

inserting A_list [A.size is 45,list.size=45]

list.clear() [list=null]

list=getB()

inserting B_list [list.size=45+49=94][B.size is 49]

why is the size of list at this time 94? 
It should be 49.list added data of A again  .

Here are  my codes:

```
private static void Insert(List<User> rootusers) throws Exception{
    String sql="insert into t_userlist(userid,username,rootuserid,rootusername,visited) values(?,?,?,?,?)";
    String sqlupdate="update t_userlist set visited=1 where userid=?";
    String sqlvisited="SELECT * from t_userlist where visited=1 and userid=";
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement psmt = null;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    for(int i=0;i<rootusers.size();i++){
        User user=rootusers.get(i);

        List<User> userlist=htmlParser.parseUserlist(user);

        if(userlist!=null){
            conn=DbUtil.getConn();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            try {
                for(int j=0;j<userlist.size();j++){


                        int visitedUser=selectUserID(sqlvisited+"'"+userlist.get(j).getUserid()+"'").size();

                        psmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                        psmt.setString(1, userlist.get(j).getUserid());
                        psmt.setString(2, userlist.get(j).getUsername());
                        psmt.setString(3, user.getUserid());
                        psmt.setString(4, user.getUsername());
                        if(visitedUser!=0){
                            psmt.setInt(5, 1);
                        }
                        else {
                            psmt.setInt(5, 0);
                        }
                        psmt.executeUpdate();
                        psmt.close();
                }


                ps=conn.prepareStatement(sqlupdate);
                ps.setString(1,user.getUserid());
                ps.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();
                ps.close();
                DbUtil.closeConn(conn);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    if(conn!=null)
                    {
                          conn.rollback(); 
                         // conn.setAutoCommit( true);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {

                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            **userlist.clear();**
            System.out.println("insert"+user.getUsername()+"successfully");
        }else {
            continue;
        }

    }

}
```

the htmlParser.parseUserlist(user) codes:

```
public static ArrayList<User> parseUserlist(User user) throws Exception{
    String userlist=GetUserlist.getUserList(user.getUserid());//just return html 
    ArrayList<User> list=new ArrayList<User>();
    if(userlist!=null){
        Document doc=Jsoup.parse(userlist);
        Elements users=doc.select("a[usercard]");

        for(Element nodeuser:users){
            //System.out.println(nodeuser.toString());
            User u=new User();
            u.setUserid(nodeuser.attr("usercard").substring(3,13));
            u.setUsername(nodeuser.text());
            u.setRootuserid(user.getUserid());
            list.add(u);
            //System.out.println(u.getUserid()+" "+u.getUsername());
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println(user.getUsername()+"没有关注任何人");
    }

    //System.out.println(users.toString());
    //System.out.println(list.get(1).getUsername());
    return list;
}
```

please help me !

Comment: Looks like `htmlParser.parseUserlist(user)` is related to this problem ... can you add it's code or tell us what library this is?

Comment: I added the code.please have a check . it just return a list.

Comment: btw : `sqlvisited+"'"+userlist.get(j).getUserid()+"'"` is a security hole **if** and only if `getUserid()` is able to return a valid SQL-string. Never concatenate data-parameters, even if your data is coming directly from the database itself ... thats called "best practise". Use prepared statements absolutely **everytime and everywhere**, even if it means unnecessary code. Even better : use JPA criteria, these are automatically escaped and somewhat secure'ish by design.

Comment: Your "parseUserList" allways creates and returns a new list, so those newly created lists must somehow be filled with the previous data as well. Can you post the code for "GetUserlist.getUserList()"? Thats one probable cause where the duplicate data might come from.

Comment: thank you,specializt. I am a novice .I will modify my code base on your advice

Comment: to:911DidBush . GetUserlist.getUserList() just return string[html] , it should not  cause the problem.

Comment: kyleson: Yes, but how does it return the string is the question. Its very possible that the returned string is not cleared with each call and it just appends the new data every time. Returning a larger string with each call...but okay...if you are sure the problem isn't there.....

Comment: to:911DidBush.!!!!!!thank you very very very very much !!!!!  What you said that enlightens me ! I  checked up the GetUserlist.getUserList() code .I am so silly! I don't clear the string variable that lead to return html string which  contains previous html string.the problem is resolved! thank you again!

Comment: kyleson: No problem, your welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong that would be a cause of your problem in the code you have provided. One thing to know is that list.Clear() is not the same as list = null; because an empty list is a list that contains no elements and clear() empties the list. In your insert method you would do better with !userList.isEmpty() (seeing how you are always creating a list and at worst returning an empty list from parseUserList.

Comment: The problem is resolved .thank you too.I will modify my code better base on your advice